# Query with mutual combination

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called "X" that has a list of my support team. We have another table called "Y" that has a list of users. I'm facing a problem to develop an output where all combinations are possible, like this:

- TABLE X (support team) = X1, X2
- TABLE Y (users to be attendent) = Y1, Y2, Y3

i need all possible PAIR combinations, between X and Y

```
X1,Y1 ; X2,Y2
X1,Y1 ; X2,Y3
X1,Y2 ; X2,Y1
X1,Y2 ; X2,Y3
X1,Y3 ; X2,Y1
X1,Y3 ; X2,Y2
```

Another Example:

[image]

Comment: What are the EXACT table structures?

Comment: The result you wrote is not possible combinations of X and Y but more combinations of (X, Y) pairs. Do you expect the result to have 4 columns (FirstX, SecondX, FirstY, SecondY)?

Comment: The table scructure is the simplest as possible (Table with a ID and NAME) for both of them

Comment: @vc74 the output must have all the possible combinations beetween X and Y (pairs). Every row is a "Scenario" and each "Scenario" should have "N" pairs and each pair contain
a combination of (SUPPORT USER + USER). A "Support User" can help one "User" at time 

this combination below is not valid because X1 is already in ocuppied in this scenario ("supporter user" X1 is helping "user" Y1 and he cant do it at the same time for Y2).

SCENARIO 1 -> (X1,Y1) and (X1,Y2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that for an unknown number of supporters you need a recursive query. Use arrays to find further supporter/supportee pairs.

```
with recursive pairs(supporter_array, supportee_array) as
(
  select ('{' || s.id || '}')::varchar[], ('{' || o.id || '}')::varchar[]
  from (select id, name from support_user order by id fetch first row only) s
  cross join other_user o
  union all
  select p.supporter_array || s.id, p.supportee_array || o.id
  from pairs p
  join support_user s on s.id > ALL (p.supporter_array)
  join other_user o on o.id <> ALL (p.supportee_array)
)
, scenarios as
(
  select *, row_number() over (order by supporter_array, supportee_array) as scenario
  from pairs
  where array_length(supporter_array, 1) = (select count(*) from support_user)
)
select scenario, unnest(supporter_array) as supporter, unnest(supportee_array) as supportee 
from scenarios
order by scenario, supporter;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SUFW27556

(Please bear with me; this is the first time I'm using PostgreSQL arrays. I tried with a multidimensional array and I tried with ARRAY, but that failed. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to write my query.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: This results in `42804: recursive query "pairs" column 1 has type character varying(3)[] in non-recursive term but type character varying[] overall`.

Comment: Ah, I assumed `id` was an integer. The easiest way is to simply use `text` instead: http://rextester.com/UMA35525

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Ah, so `text` is more array-friendly than `varchar`, somehow. Good to know. Can you explain why this is?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner that's it! works like a charm! :) thank you, i have to read a bit about recursive queries, i've never had to use this, it's great!

Answer (score 2):

This is a *join of cross joins*:

```
select (x1, y1) as pair1, (x2, y2) as pair2
from (
    select x.id as x1, y.id as y1
    from x cross join y
    ) p1
join (
    select x.id as x2, y.id as y2
    from x cross join y
    ) p2 on x1 < x2 and y1 <> y2

  pair1  |  pair2  
---------+---------
 (x1,y1) | (x2,y2)
 (x1,y1) | (x2,y3)
 (x1,y2) | (x2,y1)
 (x1,y2) | (x2,y3)
 (x1,y3) | (x2,y1)
 (x1,y3) | (x2,y2)
(6 rows)
```

[SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e122a/1)

Comment: almost it, your example works, but only if table X has 2 entries. Look at my example in excel, the results are listed with their respective scenario besides columns for each pair. 
If i Add one more registry in table "SUPPORT USER" you should change your query to 3 pairs column and so on

Comment: I see, with these assumptions a proper choice seems to be a recursive solution. I think Thorsten answer is a good one.